# how to make these two comparisons into 1 (bit logics)

Tags: if-statement

input three integers, n, tag and flag.

if flag = 0 then

```
return ((n & tag) == tag);
```

if flag != 0 then

```
return ((n & tag) != tag);
```

Ideally, I want something simple without if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If flag can be converted to a bool, it can be simplified to:

```
return !(flag ^ ((n & tag) == tag))
```

Comment: `^` is bitwise xor, I think you want `!=`

Comment: Bitwise xor is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the flag to a bool. In C++:

```
 bool b_flag = flag;
 return !b_flag * ((n & tag) == tag) + b_flag * ((n & tag) != tag);
```

Or you could use a ternary operator.